# OpenNLP error while parsing the training file for document categorization

Tags: opennlp

I am trying to work on the document classifier with opennlp. But I am having a hard time with the training file. I am getting the following error while opennlp is reading the file:

```
Indexing events using cutoff of 5

    Computing event counts...  done. 17 events
    Indexing...  Dropped event greetings:[bow=hello]
Dropped event greetings:[bow=hi]
Dropped event greetings:[bow=salam]
Dropped event internet_problem:[bow=internet]
Dropped event internet_problem:[bow=no, bow=data]
Dropped event internet_problem:[bow=data, bow=not, bow=working]
Dropped event internet_problem:[bow=not, bow=able, bow=to, bow=open, bow=website]
Dropped event internet_problem:[bow=browsing, bow=issue]
Dropped event balance_problem:[bow=balance]
Dropped event balance_problem:[bow=usage]
Dropped event balance_problem:[bow=bill, bow=amount]
Dropped event balance_problem:[bow=billed]
Dropped event voice_problem:[bow=signals]
Dropped event voice_problem:[bow=call]
Dropped event voice_problem:[bow=voice]
Dropped event voice_problem:[bow=call, bow=drop]
Dropped event voice_problem:[bow=not, bow=connecting]
done.
Sorting and merging events... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.AbstractDataIndexer.sortAndMerge(AbstractDataIndexer.java:89)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TwoPassDataIndexer.<init>(TwoPassDataIndexer.java:105)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.getDataIndexer(AbstractEventTrainer.java:74)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.AbstractEventTrainer.train(AbstractEventTrainer.java:91)
    at opennlp.tools.ml.model.TrainUtil.train(TrainUtil.java:53)
    at opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentCategorizerME.train(DocumentCategorizerME.java:204)
    at com.nlp.CategoryTrainUtil.trainModel(CategoryTrainUtil.java:39)
    at com.nlp.Boot.main(Boot.java:12)
```

My training file looks like:

```
greetings hello
greetings hi
greetings salam
internet_problem internet
internet_problem no data
internet_problem data not working
internet_problem not able to open website
internet_problem browsing issue
balance_problem balance
balance_problem usage
balance_problem bill amount
balance_problem billed
voice_problem signals
voice_problem call
voice_problem voice
voice_problem call drop
voice_problem not connecting
```

I am not getting what I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

the first line says `Indexing events using cutoff of 5`

which probably means you have to give a minimum of 5 examples each for classification. so, give two more examples for `greeting` and the others wherever there aren't 5 in your training data.

Alternatively, you can decrease your cutoff to 3 if you don't have enough training data, but this will not give you good results.

Hope this helps!